# How to add ripple effect to "entire" cardview in android

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I am new to Android programming. I want to add ripple effect to cardview. Actually I found the solution, however, after touching cardview element, it seems that the effect doesn't cover entire cardview. I mean that the effect fades out suddenly and doesn't reach the edges of the cardview.
The result which I'm getting is as follows:

[image]

While I want something like this one posted in this [blog post](http://michaelevans.org/blog/2015/05/07/android-ripples-with-rounded-corners/).

This is the approach I have tried:

**cardview_item.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/MyCardViewStyle"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:id="@+id/appletCard"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardDefaultBg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_effect"
        >

      //Some TextViews here ...

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is the **ripple_effect.xml** in the drawable-v21 package:

```
<ripple
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/mask"
    android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
</ripple>
```

If it is important, I use support library.

Comment: Ripples dont necessarily go to the edge

Comment: So is there a solution to make them go to the edges? @tyczj

Comment: This is good actually, i used this ripple. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should apply `mask` to your ripple. Try this:

```or-tag-here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/card_corner_radius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: @inverted_index then you should consider on usage third-party libraries or writing your own ripple animation on user touches a card . Look for an example lib [here](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect).

Comment: As I use lots of libraries in my application, I've no tendency of importing useless libraries. However, writing my own ripple animation is a good idea in this case :) thank you. @ArtyomDorosh

Answer (score 1):

You can use android default ripple effect with `"?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/appletCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                style="@style/MyCardViewStyle"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardDefaultBg">


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Or create custom

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/RippleColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/RippleColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/backColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

If you want that effect reach the edges, use [this library](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) that provides you `OnRippleCompleteListener`, so you can wait until it finish effect and reach the edges

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use the default ripple effect. But the problem is not that. I want to make (or even force) effect continue rippling to the edges of the cardview. Unfortunately, the default ripple effect doesn't provide it.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the similar applications which are using ripple effect for their ui elements, I found out that the effect has changed over different versions of Android. The case I'm looking for is used in Lollipop Android devices. So as I ran the emulator on API 25 (Nogut), I didn't get the desired result.

Thank you all for ur responses.